# htacces mac os not working with pseudo directory

Tags: macos, .htaccess

i managed to make htaccess working on mac os x but the subcateg rule returns a file not found (404) as i guess does search from the articles folder(?)

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ks

RewriteRule ^articles/(.*).html$ articles.cfm?subcateg=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^articles.html$ articles.cfm [NC,L]
```

The second one seems to be working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, your `RewriteBase` is `/ks/` folder, which means you access it with `domain.com/ks/articles/xxxxx.html` or `domain.com/ks/articles.html` and your htaccess is in `/ks/` folder.

If that's right, you should disable `MultiViews` option to avoid your problem.
This code should work on osx, too

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ks/

RewriteRule ^articles/(.+?)\.html$ articles.cfm?subcateg=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^articles\.html$ articles.cfm [NC,L]
```